# Write a 2-form in terms of standard basis

Tags: differential-forms

Solving problem 4.2 in Tu's *Introduction to manifolds*. Not homework, voluntarily problem solving related to a course I am following.

A bilinear function $\omega_p$ on the tangent space $T_p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is defined as 
\begin{align}
\omega_p(a,b) &= \omega_p([a_1, a_2, a_3]^T, [b_1,b_2,b_3]^T) \\
&= p_3 det 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
The point $p = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$ and tangent vectors $a,b$. Write $\omega$ in terms of basis 2-forms $dx_i \wedge dx_j$ at each point.

I am thinking that the given determinant corresponds to the area form $dx \wedge dy$. So my answer is that $$\omega = p_3 dx \wedge dy$$ at all points. The intuition is that $p_3$ is projected to a parallellogram in the $x-y$ plane. Is that correct?

Comment: You mean $\omega_p = p_3\,dx\wedge dy$. $p_3$ is just the third coordinate of the point $p$, so what does your "$p_3$ is projected to ..." mean? You project the parallelogram spanned by $a,b$ to the $xy$-plane, yes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was wrong. Is it ok to say that $p_3$ scales the parallellogram projected to the $xy$-plane?

Comment: Yes, or just takes a scalar multiple of it. If $p_3<0$, scaling won't quite work.

Comment: Thanks, I you will formulate an answer I will happily accept and upvote. Otherwise I could answer myself based on your comments. You decide :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, your answer $\omega_p = p_3 dx\wedge dy$ is correct. When you apply this to a pair of vectors, $\omega_p(a,b)$ gives the signed area of the projection of the parallelogram spanned by $a$ and $b$ onto the $xy$-plane, scaled by a factor of $p_3$.